# how to add multiple gif watermakr in one video usign ffmpeg in android

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, gif, video-watermarking

i want to create video with multiple gif images as sticker .i have already use ffmpeg library for create normal video.

below code i have already use:

String[] cmd={"-i",margefilePath,"-ignore_loop","0","-i","unnamed.gif","-i","unnamed.gif","-i","unnamed.gif","-i","unnamed.gif","-i","unnamed.gif","-filter_complex","[0][1]overlay=x=W-w:y=0[tr];[tr][2]overlay=x=0:y=0[tl];[tl][3]overlay=x=W-w:y=H-h[br];[br][4]overlay=x=0:y=H-h[bl];[bl][5]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2","out.mp4"};

Please help me how can i add multiple gif images in video . Thanks in advance :) and sorry for bad english

Comment: Please add a tag for the programming language used

Comment: Your command already add multiple gif watermakr in one video usign ffmpeg in android. What is the actual problem?

Comment: ffmpeg commands run infinity time means ffmpeg excution not stop.

Comment: did you found solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Add `:shortest=1` in overlay tag like `[bl][5]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2:shortest=1` in each GIF loop.